# How to avoid checkbox being selected when clicking on table row

Tags: jquery, angularjs, checkbox, html-table

I have a table with one of the columns a checkbox that I need to activate or not depending on a certain logic.

My problem is even when the checkbox is deactivated, when I click away from the checkbox, at the table row, the checkbox get selected.

What is best approach to fix this?
Make the row tables deactivated too?

```
 <table st-safe-src="sampleOverview.dataSet" st-table="sampleOverview.displayed" class="table table-striped">
    <tr ng-repeat="sample in sampleOverview.displayed track by $index" ng-click="sample.selected = !sample.selected" ng-class="{success: sample.selected, warning : sample.deviceId == null || sample.methodId == null }" ng-disabled="sample.deviceId == null || sample.methodId == null">
                <td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">{{sample.lab}}</td>
                <td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">{{sample.subLab}}</td>
                <td>{{sample.deviceLimsCode}}</td>
                <td>{{sample.methodLimsCode}}</td>
                <td>{{sample.sampleCode}}</td>
                <td class="text-center hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="sample.selected" ng-click="sampleOverview.selectSample($event, sample)" ng-disabled="sample.deviceId == null || sample.methodId == null">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `ng-click` on row. Remove it. Your `ng-click` on table row is triggering the value of checkbox model to change. You can either change the name of checkbox's ng-model or remove ng-click on table or change the variables used in the latter.

```
 <table st-safe-src="sampleOverview.dataSet" st-table="sampleOverview.displayed" class="table table-striped">
    <tr ng-repeat="sample in sampleOverview.displayed track by $index" ng-class="{success: sample.selected, warning : sample.deviceId == null || sample.methodId == null }" ng-disabled="sample.deviceId == null || sample.methodId == null">
                <td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">{{sample.lab}}</td>
                <td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">{{sample.subLab}}</td>
                <td>{{sample.deviceLimsCode}}</td>
                <td>{{sample.methodLimsCode}}</td>
                <td>{{sample.sampleCode}}</td>
                <td class="text-center hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="sample.selected" ng-click="sampleOverview.selectSample($event, sample)" ng-disabled="sample.deviceId == null || sample.methodId == null">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Or If you want to add a class to your row based on `ng-click`, then change the variables name like below

```
<table st-safe-src="sampleOverview.dataSet" st-table="sampleOverview.displayed" class="table table-striped">
    <tr ng-repeat="sample in sampleOverview.displayed track by $index" ng-click="selectedVal = !selectedVal" ng-class="{success: selectedVal, warning : sample.deviceId == null || sample.methodId == null }" ng-disabled="sample.deviceId == null || sample.methodId == null">
                <td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">{{sample.lab}}</td>
                <td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">{{sample.subLab}}</td>
                <td>{{sample.deviceLimsCode}}</td>
                <td>{{sample.methodLimsCode}}</td>
                <td>{{sample.sampleCode}}</td>
                <td class="text-center hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="sample.selected" ng-click="sampleOverview.selectSample($event, sample)" ng-disabled="sample.deviceId == null || sample.methodId == null">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

And initialise selectedVal in your controller

Comment: Hey Vivz, thanks for the reply. Is there a way to keep the ng-click and block the propagation? I've tried ng-click="sample.selected = !sample.selected; $event.stopPropagation();" It didn't work

Comment: Why do you need the ng-model of checkbox to be the same as once inside ng-click and why are u toggling them

Comment: Hi,  Vivz. Thanks for replying. I need that because my checkbox do not appear when I shift to mobile view. That ng-click make the table selectable when The mobile view is on

Comment: Then use a different variable for ng-click like in the second solution above

Comment: Or you can define a class for your mobile-view and enable the row click only if it is mobile view

Comment: Thanks Vivz, both of your suggestions were good. Have a great week end ;-)